# arg max in Java 8 streams?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, argmax

I often need the maximum element of a collection according to the maximization of a  criterion which produces a double or int value. Streams have the max() function which requires me to implement a comparator, which I find cumbersome. Is there a more concise syntax, such as `names.stream().argmax(String::length)` in the following example?

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class ArgMax
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        List<String> names = Arrays.asList("John","Joe","Marilyn");
        String longestName = names.stream().max((String s,String t)->(Integer.compare(s.length(),t.length()))).get();
        System.out.println(longestName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Am I missing something or are none of the solution below actually returning Argmax().  They should return the *index* of the max value, not the value itself.  That is a very different problem.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arg_max

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use

```
String longestName = names.stream().max(Comparator.comparing(String::length)).get();
```

to compare elements on some property (can be more complex than that, but doesn't have to).

[As Brian suggests in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27606185/arg-max-in-java-8-streams/27606219?noredirect=1#comment43642462_27606219), using `Optional#get()` like this is unsafe if there's a possibility that the `Stream` is empty. You'd be better suited to use one of the safer retrieval methods, such as [`Optional#orElse(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElse-T-) which will give you some default value if there is no max.

Comment: Gah!  Don't use raw `get()` at the end of this, otherwise you will throw NSEE if the stream is empty.  Use a safe method like `orElse`, `orElseThrow`, or `ifPresent`.

Comment: @BrianGoetz I think we've discovered one of Brian's allergies. He sneezes whenever I write `Optional.get()` too.

Comment: @StuartMarks Indeed so.  We should have never called it `get`.  We should have called it `getOrThrow()` or `orElseThrow()` or `getUnsafely()` or probably just `getOrThrowNoSuchElementExcpetionIfThisOptionalIsNotPresent()`.

Comment: In this case how do I get the index of longestName value? I assume that `names.indexOf(longestName)` is OK?

Comment: @zygimantus: if you can live with a second linear search, yes. Otherwise, use `IntStream.range(0, names.length()).boxed().max(Comparator.comparingInt(ix -> names.get().length())` to search for the index in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

I think one should consider that while `max`/`min` are unique, this is of course not guaranteed for the `argMax`/`argMin`; this in particular implies that the type of the reduction should be a collection, such as for instance a `List`. This requires a bit more work than suggested above.

The following `ArgMaxCollector<T>` class provides a simple implementation of such a reduction. The `main` shows an application of such class to compute the `argMax`/`argMin` of the set of strings

```
one two three four five six seven
```

ordered by their length. The output (reporting the result of the `argMax` and `argMin` collectors respectively) should be

```
[three, seven]
[one, two, six]
```

that are the two longest and the three shortest strings respectively.

This is my first attempt at using the new Java 8 stream APIs, so any comment will be more than welcome!

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collector;

class ArgMaxCollector<T> {

    private T max = null;
    private ArrayList<T> argMax = new ArrayList<T>();
    private Comparator<? super T> comparator;

    private ArgMaxCollector( Comparator<? super T> comparator ) {
        this.comparator = comparator;
    }

    public void accept( T element ) {
        int cmp = max == null ? -1 : comparator.compare( max, element );
        if ( cmp < 0 ) {
            max = element;
            argMax.clear();
            argMax.add( element );
        } else if ( cmp == 0 )
            argMax.add( element );
    }

    public void combine( ArgMaxCollector<T> other ) {
        int cmp = comparator.compare( max, other.max );
        if ( cmp < 0 ) {
            max = other.max;
            argMax = other.argMax;
        } else if ( cmp == 0 ) {
            argMax.addAll( other.argMax );
        }
    }

    public List<T> get() {
        return argMax;
    }

    public static <T> Collector<T, ArgMaxCollector<T>, List<T>> collector( Comparator<? super T> comparator ) {
        return Collector.of(
            () -> new ArgMaxCollector<T>( comparator ),
            ( a, b ) -> a.accept( b ),
            ( a, b ) ->{ a.combine(b); return a; },
            a -> a.get() 
        );
    }
}

public class ArgMax {

    public static void main( String[] args ) {

        List<String> names = Arrays.asList( new String[] { "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven" } );

        Collector<String, ArgMaxCollector<String>, List<String>> argMax = ArgMaxCollector.collector( Comparator.comparing( String::length ) );
        Collector<String, ArgMaxCollector<String>, List<String>> argMin = ArgMaxCollector.collector( Comparator.comparing( String::length ).reversed() );

        System.out.println( names.stream().collect( argMax ) );
        System.out.println( names.stream().collect( argMin ) );

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy efficient solution here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/63201174/2069400

```
/** return argmin item, else null if none.  NAN scores are skipped */
public static <T> T argmin(Stream<T> stream, ToDoubleFunction<T> scorer) {
    Double min = null;
    T argmin = null;
    for (T p: (Iterable<T>) stream::iterator) {
        double score = scorer.applyAsDouble(p);
        if (min==null || min > score) {
            min = score;
            argmin = p;
        }
    }
    return argmin;
}
```

Comment: +1. This minimizes the number of calls to `scorer`. It calls it `n`  times. In contrast, the `Stream::min()` calls the `Comparator.comparing` `(n-1)*2` times. Where `n` is number of elements in the stream. This is mighty important, if the comparator is expensive.