# Arg-min using a stream of ints

Tags: concurrency, java-8, java-stream

I would like to find, using Java streams, an integer i, in the range {1,...1000}, for which the function sin(i/100) is smallest. I tried to use min with comparator, as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27606185/827927):

```
    Comparator<Integer> sineComparator = (i,j) -> 
        Double.compare(Math.sin(i/100.0), Math.sin(j/100.0));
    IntStream.range(1,1000)
    .min(sineComparator);
```

but it did not work since an IntStream does not have a variant of min that accepts a comparator. What can I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use [`boxed()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#boxed--) to convert `IntStream` to `Stream<Integer>` which will allow you to use `min` with a comparator:

```
IntStream.range(1, 1000)
            .boxed()
            .min(sineComparator)
```

Alternatively, you can avoid boxing but at the cost of reduced clarity:

```
IntStream.range(1,1000)
            .reduce((i,j) -> sineComparator.compare(i, j) <= 0 ? i : j)
```

On a separate note, you can create your comparator using `Comparator.comparingDouble`:

```
Comparator<Integer> sineComparator = Comparator.comparingDouble(i -> Math.sin(i/100.0));
```

Comment: Or `(int)(150*Math.PI)`…